# Where is @mediapipe/camera_utils npm module source code?

Tags: javascript, npm, webcam, mediapipe

[MediaPipe](https://mediapipe.dev/) project's source code is hosted at https://github.com/google/mediapipe

We can use MediaPipe using JavaScript also in Browser given at [MediaPipe in JavaScript](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/javascript.html)

While using MediaPipe with JavaScript we need to use [@mediapipe/camera_utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mediapipe/camera_utils) module whose source code I am looking for. Its not available on https://github.com/google/mediapipe

I found minified code at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/control_utils/control_utils.js which is not so readable even after un-minifing it.

So where is source code of [`@mediapipe/camera_utils`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mediapipe/camera_utils)?

Comment: Did you get an answer ? I'm looking for a documentation of camera_utils to select the right camera

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeEncausse: you can read and modify minified code of `camera_util` its very small code. minifiled code link is given in question.

Comment: By accident I found some of the JavaScript code in the tfjs-models repo. For example here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/face-landmarks-detection/src/mediapipe.
But no sign of `control_utils`